# Two-way bind Dictionary<string, byte> in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, viewmodel

I have two `Dictionary<string, byte>` properties in my model that should validate properly with from 0 to 5 items.  For example the property `skill (string dropDownListLabel, byte years)`.

Because I need to support non-javascript clients, I render all 5 input pairs to the browser, only binding existing dictionary items, and life is great. This gives 5 empty input pairs for a new plain HTML form, each with unique input names, which I also want.

Here's the serialization (input names) I use:

```
skill[0].Key = "", skill[0].Value = ""
 ... three more pairs ...
skill[4].Key = "", skill[4].Value = ""
```

But on POST, for Key/Value pairs with neither Key nor Value specified, DefaultModelBinder validation errors result on Value.

Is there a type and serialization I can use that will validate in DefaultModelBinder when *both* or *neither* Key and Value are POSTed, so MVC does as much work for me as possible, only adding pairs into a collection when they have content?

Thanks,
Shannon

Comment: I followed Darin's second half of the accepted answer below. I pre-saturated a List<T> with null values, where T implements IValidatable to ensure both OR neither values are provided. Further I static methods on T to convert a List<T> to/from the corresponding IEnumerable<EntityObject>, as a convenient place to stash the saturation/dehydration process. Finally, I also placed the uniqueness comparison there and call it from IValidatable on the top-level model. This also solved a problem with MVC not using the configured DataAnnotationValidation "Value Required" message for Dictionary items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind an empty string to a value type (`byte`) so the default model binder marks your model as invalid. If you want to allow empty values you should use a nullable byte:

```
Dictionary<string, byte?>
```

---

UPDATE:

Another possibility is to use a collection of a custom type containing two properties each representing respectively the key and the value. Then use strongly typed helpers and editor templates in your view so that you don't have to worry about the wire format and finally you will need to ensure that the keys are unique so you will need a custom validator. Personally I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for this part but if you are using data annotations you will need a custom attribute which will be used to decorate the collection property in the view model.

Comment: That's the opposite behavior I desire, creating empty dictionary items.  And there can't be 5 identical empty strings bound to Key.  I don't want it to bind that item at all, if both Key and Value are empty strings. Binding occurs by enumerating through the Model properties, not through form values, right? So I figure there may be another data type that will work the way I want. I only want a validation error if one value is set but not the other, or if duplicate strings are posted.

Comment: If this were an AJAX-only page, I'd only POST the pairs with content, and Dictionary would be fine.  It's not AJAX only, so I want to know what the best practice is.

Comment: @shannon, binding occurs based on whatever values are sent in the request. So if you send empty values the default model binder will try to bind them. Obviously you cannot use the same key in a dictionary, that would be contradictory to what a dictionary is in the first place. So the best practice in this case would be to use some custom view model and not dictionary.

Comment: @Darin: right, makes total sense. given my desire for a variable number of unique keys with mandatory associated values, any suggestions on model structure, wire format, and validation process? Again, I just want to code the least and get the most out of MVC. I see myself running into this need again in the near future.

Comment: @shannon, you could use a collection of a custom type containing two properties each representing respectively the key and the value. Then use strongly typed helpers and editor templates in your view so that you don't have to worry about the wire format and finally you will need to ensure that the keys are unique so you will need a custom validator. Personally I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for this part but if you are using data annotations you will need a custom attribute which will be used to decorate the collection property in the view model.

Comment: @Darin: Thanks, I'm on it. I assume I can stick the key-uniqueness test right on the Model.ICollection property using [CustomValidator]? And to use editor templates in the way you suggest, you mean I should just add empty items into the Model.ICollection for non AJAX clients to fill?

Comment: @Darin: If you please add your last comment as an answer I'll accept it.